# PHP and the balance point of an array

Tags: php

Has anyone had any experience using PHP to find the balance point of an array?

I'm struggling to find a solution or any information on how to achieve this.

Comment: The algorithm looks pretty simple to implement why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Do you have a link to the algorithm please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47GNZCxE6ko

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arrayData = array(1,2,3,2,1);
for($i=0;$i<count($arrayData);$i++)
{
    $sumLeft = 0;
    $sumRight = 0;
    for($key=0; $key <= $i; $key++)
    {
        $sumLeft += $arrayData[$key];
    }
    for($key=$i; $key < count($arrayData); $key++)
    {
        $sumRight += $arrayData[$key];
    }
    if($sumLeft == $sumRight)
    {
        echo "Array Possition : "$i;
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: While it of course is appreciated of you to answer a question, please explain it and *at least* properly format it.